# Python text to file on change

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Im seeking after a method to update name.txt from a textarea (with lot of text) BUT i dont want to have a submit button. The ide is that when there is change in text area, then automatic save the content.

Hope maybe someone can give me a direction I can search in :-)

```
import tkinter as tk

def writefile():
    with open("./name.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.truncate(0)
        f.writelines(name.get())
        print("File has been written !")
        root.update()

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('700x600')
root.title("Writers tool")
root.rowconfigure(0, minsize=800, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, minsize=800, weight=1)


frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "yellow")
frame.place(relwidth = 2, relheight = 1)
frame.pack()

name = tk.StringVar()
name.trace("w", lambda l, idx, mode: writefile())
entry = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=100)
entry.place(relx = 0.25, rely = 50, relwidth=10)


entry.place(relx = 0.25, rely = 0.05, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.1)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> so how can I change the input field to a textarea and still have textvariable = name passed through to update name.txt?

You can't. The `Text` widget doesn't support the `textvariable` option. You don't need it though, you can get the data from the widget the same as you would with `textvariable`. Namely, by calling the `get` method on the widget.

In your specific case, you can modify `writefile` to look like this:

```
def writefile():
    data = entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    with open("./name.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.truncate(0)
        f.writelines(data)
        print("File has been written !")
        root.update()
```

Comment: I've updated my Text () ... but nothing comes through to name.txt :-( Can you se what im doing wrong?

Comment: @HenrikCWiberg: you can't use `trace` on the `Text` widget, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: OK, do you have any idea how to get the content from a text area, into the name.txt without a submit button?

Comment: @HenrikCWiberg: yes, but that's a separate question. The comment section isn't designed for large conversations or large answers. You should either ask a new question, or edit your question to make it more clear that you're wanting to save the data on every keystroke.

Comment: Thanks for your reply